# How I can access Adapter from Fragment in MainActivity? I am using tabs with viewpager so no transaction etc method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to access adapter from fragment let say A
in Activity B.in activity B. I am adding new data to adapter from database and want to notify adapter.

**please help how I can access the adapter in Activity B.**

Comment: Why do you want to access the adapter at all?

Comment: I'm trying to access the adapter because that is where the list is being submitted and when I get a brand new list from the database through an action bar in main activity, it doesn't update the adapter.  When I interact with the fragment directly, it changes but will only change items in the currently submitted list.  Otherwise I have to navigate away and back, then it will give me the proper list.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the adapter which you want to notify in that particular fragment and then use `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after passing the data to the adapter.

Example:

```
MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),your data to pass);
//set your recycler view or any other view to which you want to set this adapter

//notify that the data has changed


myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: my question is how to get Adapter object from fragment in an Activity?

Comment: use getActivity().myAdapter to get adapter object in a fragment.

Comment: my question is how to get Adapter object from fragment in an Activity?

Comment: you can declare as many adapter objects as you want right?lets say if you have an adapter named yourAdapter and you can declare it in your fragment as well as your activity..please be specific,edit the question and upload the code and describe the problems using that code..